# Create new ID on realtime firebase database in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying create a new unique ID of length 5, consisting of only uppercase letters and numbers, on a realtime firebase database. My thinking to solve this problem was to create an ID, check if this already exists on the database, and if so, create a new ID and repeat until a unique ID is found. I'm unsure how to solve this with the asynchronous nature of database calls. I've tried solving it using promises, but I am not sure how to fix this using recursive promises.

This is as far as I got:

```
const database = firebase.database();

function createRoom() {
    //Create random ID of length 5 consisting of only uppercase letters and numbers
    const ID = createID(5);

    return new Promise((success) => {
        //Check if ID already exists in database
        exists(ID).then(() => {
            return createRoom()
        }).catch(() => {
            success(ID)
        });
    });
}

function exists(ID) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        database.ref('rooms').child(ID).once('value', snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                resolve()
            } else {
                reject()
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: It's generally a bad practice to use `new Promise` when you already have a promise to deal with.  Just use that promise directly - don't wrap it in a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
let ID = database.collection('someCollection').doc().id;
```

This will create a unique ID

Comment: Problem is, the ID needs to be a string of length 5 consisting of only uppercase letters and numbers

Comment: Well, you didn't say that on the question. You should add that restriction. EDIT: I see it now on code comments, sorry. Maybe you could put it outside code too

Comment: OP uses Realtime Database, while your code is for Cloud Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and have different APIs.

Comment: You could cut the ID string to 5 characters and use the function ´toUpperCase()´

Comment: Pretty sure that would allow collisions. Eg. "FOOBA123" and "FOOBA789" are unique, but by cutting the string to 5 characters, they amount to the same

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen ohh you are right, my bad. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @MaltDew Yes, that would be a problem.

Comment: By the other hand, could you consider using the auto generated ID from firebase? Or use a 5 length Id is really necessary?

Comment: IDs of length 5 are necessary, as users can share and join using these IDs